# Como criar sublistas obedecendo a conexão de células em uma matriz

Tags: lista, matriz

Amigos, estou tentando criar sublistas a partir de uma matriz para segmentar células que estão conectadas, como por exemplo a matriz abaixo:
[image: matriz utilizada no exemplo]

Dessa matriz obtenho essa lista com as células pintadas:

```
lista = [[1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 5], [2, 6], [3, 2], [3, 5], [3, 6], [6,1], [6, 4], [6, 5], [7,1], [7, 4], [7, 5]]
```

Desejo como resultado, sublistas com as células amarelas, agrupadas assim:

```
[[1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 2]],
[[2, 5], [2, 6], [3, 5], [3, 6]]
[[6,1], [7,1]]
[[6, 4], [6, 5], [7, 4], [7, 5]]
```

Não sei se é possível, mas até o momento, com a função abaixo:

```
def group_by_diff(group, diff=1):
    container = []
    new_group = [group[0]] 
    for i in range(1,len(group)):
        if((group[i][0] - group[i-1][0] > diff) or (group[i][1] - group[i-1][1] > diff)):
            container.append(new_group)
            new_group = [group[i]]
        else:
            new_group.append(group[i])
    if(len(new_group) > 0):
        container.append(new_group)
    return container
```

Eu consigo esse resultado somente:

```
[[1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3]], 
[[2, 5], [2, 6], [3, 2]], 
[[3, 5], [3, 6]], 
[[6, 1]], 
[[6, 4], [6, 5], [7, 1]], 
[[7, 4], [7, 5]]
```

O que não atende, nesse exemplo criaram 6 sublistas, onde na verdade só deve ser criada 4 aglomerações, de acordo com a imagem.

Espero ter me feito entender. De já agradeço.